# Why does Blockchain.info's My Wallet tx volume seem to exceed to total bitcoin network volume?

Tags: blockchain.info

I was looking at Blockchain.info's tx volume (in BTC) over the previous year. It goes from about 100k to 400k BTC per day with a peak of over 850k BTC around November.
https://blockchain.info/charts/my-wallet-transaction-volume

However, if you look at their graph of the total bitcoin network tx volume over a similar time perdiod, it goes from 100k to 300k without similar peaks.
https://blockchain.info/charts/estimated-transaction-volume

This makes it seem like they are doing more volume than the entire network.  Is this is a bug, or are they counting something differently (like maybe a send between two wallets is counted twice)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [estimated transaction volume chart](https://blockchain.info/charts/estimated-transaction-volume) is processed in a way that it removes any change and send-to-self values inside a transaction from its total value. If you want to see the raw chart then you should be looking at the [output volume chart](https://blockchain.info/charts/output-volume) instead.

Comment: Are you saying that https://blockchain.info/charts/my-wallet-transaction-volume is measuring total output volume, so it is more comparable to https://blockchain.info/charts/output-volume ?  I'm not sure why my-wallet volume would measure total outputs - I'm assuming they have the data for the real amount entered by the user?

Comment: Yes, https://blockchain.info/charts/my-wallet-transaction-volume displays the transaction volume of the `My Wallet` service, while https://blockchain.info/charts/output-volume displays the total value of all transaction outputs per day which includes coins that were returned to the sender as change. AFAIK an `estimated transaction volume` chart is not currently publicly available for `My Wallet` transactions.

Comment: Got it - I think you're right this must be the reason.  Seems a bit misleading though because https://blockchain.info/charts/my-wallet-transaction-volume is not showing transaction volume like you said, it is showing total outputs.